# Query with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 columns in my DB table as follows.
1. START_TIME
2. END_TIME
3. INDEX_NO

```
Sample records below

INDEX_NO                END_TIME                        START_TIME                      
------------- ------------------------------- -------------------------------
I152         13-JAN-14 02.30.00.000000000 AM 13-JAN-14 12.10.00.000000000 AM 
I151         13-JAN-14 05.30.00.000000000 AM 13-JAN-14 03.15.00.000000000 AM 
I152         20-JAN-14 02.30.00.000000000 AM 20-JAN-14 12.10.00.000000000 AM 
I151         20-JAN-14 05.30.00.000000000 AM 20-JAN-14 03.15.00.000000000 AM
```

From the above result set i need extract the `MIN(START_TIME)` and `MAX(END_TIME)` along with the `INDEX_NO` of the record with `MIN(START_TIME)`

```
To summarize the expected output is as follows.

INDEX_NO                END_TIME                        START_TIME                      
    ------------- ------------------------------- -------------------------------
    I152         20-JAN-14 05.30.00.000000000 AM 13-JAN-14 12.10.00.000000000 AM
```

Can anyone help me with a query of minimal cost to do the above extraction?

i am using oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) function will come handy here.

```
select min(index_no) keep(dense_rank first order by start_time),
       max(end_time),
       min(start_time)
from mytab;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35455/2).

Comment: Wow, every time I see queries like this I tell myself I need to read and practise the aggregate functions.

Answer (score -1):

You start by writing the inner query, which finds the min time and the max time. You then write a query that selects the correct fields from the table, join it against the inner query with the min_time field.

This will produce multiple rows if there are several rows with the same minimum start time.

```
SELECT 
    mt.INDEX_NO,
    mt.START_TIME,
    t."max_time"
FROM MyTable mt
JOIN
(
SELECT
    min(START_TIME) as "min_time",
    max(END_TIME) as "max_time"
FROM MyTable
) t
ON mt.START_TIME = t."min_time"
;
```